# What does it mean when the `[]` are missed out from this code?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have written this bit of code

```
let content = new Immutable.Map({
    metadata: new Immutable.Map({
      cities: 2
    }),
    data: new Immutable.List(
      new Immutable.Map({
        code: 'a',
        label: 'Sydney',
        percentage: 35 / 40,
      }),
      new Immutable.Map({
        code: 'b',
        label: 'Melbourne',
        percentage: 22 / 40,
      }),
    ),
   })
```

When I do `content.getIn(['data'])` I get a `['code', 'a']`. But I am actually expecting a list of map objects like this `[{'code':'a', 'label':'Sydney', 'percentage':0.875}, [...]}`

I realised it is because I did not put in a pair of `[]` to enclose the `Map` objects properly. It will work as expected once I put them in:

```
let content = new Immutable.Map({
    metadata: new Immutable.Map({
      cities: 2
    }),
    data: new Immutable.List([  // <-- missed [
      new Immutable.Map({
        code: 'a',
        label: 'Sydney',
        percentage: 35 / 40,
      }),
      new Immutable.Map({
        code: 'b',
        label: 'Melbourne',
        percentage: 22 / 40,
      }),
    ]),    // <- missed ']'
   })
```

However there is no error when my original version of code is compiled to javascript. How does es6 parser actually understands it? Why the two `map` objects get flattened and why `ImmutableList` accepts the parameters without compliant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does it mean when the `[]` are missed out from this code?

It means that you are passing *two* arguments to `Immutable.List` instead of one. Simplified example:

```
// two arguments
foo(a, b)
// vs
// array as single argument
foo([a, b])
```

If you [look at the source](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/List.js) you'll see that `Immutable.List` only does something with the first argument and ignores the second.

So your first example is equivalent to

```
   data: new Immutable.List(
      new Immutable.Map({
        code: 'a',
        label: 'Sydney',
        percentage: 35 / 40,
      }),
    ),
```

How exactly it derives `['code', 'a']` from it is specific to immutable-js. It seems to convert the argument to an iterable one way or the other. You can probably figure it out by following the source code.

> Why the two map objects get flattened

They don't.

> why `ImmutableList` accepts the parameters without compliant?

JavaScript is dynamically typed and you can pass as many (or few) arguments as you want to a function, irrespectively of its formal parameters.

`Immutable.List` seems to be implemented in such a way to accept any kind of "iterable" and it tries to make the best out of the value you pass to it.